# Why does deferring TextBox.setFocus(true) work?

Tags: gwt

In the process of helping speed up user workflow I wanted to set focus to a [TextBox](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TextBox.html). I started by simply adding the line `queryBox.setFocus(true);` to a view method. This, however, didn't work. What worked was deferring the call:

```
  Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {

     @Override
     public void execute() {
        queryBox.setFocus(true);
     }
  });
```

Why did it work, vs. my first attempt?

### Update

From the reference provided by Baadshah below, it seems this is an [existing GWT issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=1849), according to which, "Basically, setFocus() just doesn't work unless its wrapped in 
DeferredCommand most of the time."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YES ,queryBox.setFocus(true); wont work if the `queryBox` not yet attached to `DOM.`
The `TextBox` needs to be attached to the `document` before you can `focus` it.

You are right,the `browser` does take time to load the `DOM` although this `delay` is not visible to  us.

We exactly dont know when the `load`(i mean attaching to document) of `textbox` was being completed.

So by using `schedular` we are making our self to wait `some time` until the rendering finishes,to apply the `focus` on rendered `textbox`.

Here is an interested [**discussion**](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?fromgroups#!topic/google-web-toolkit/R6Zp3I5rJGk) on the same.